# "error: no '...' member function declared in class '...'" only when using -mwindows option in g++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

I am trying to make a game using SDL, VS Code and g++ compiler, but there's an error that i find annoying.
I use the -mwindows option on the g++ compiler to hide the console window that comes together with the SDL window, but the error only appears when i'm using it (when commented, it compiles without an error, but has that annoying console window on the back).
The error:

```
g++ -g -Wall -mwindows -IG:/SDL2-2.0.8/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/ Draw/draw.cpp Game/game_object.cpp Game/game.cpp main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -LG:/SDL2-2.0.8/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -std=c++11 <

Game/game_object.cpp:10:47: error: no 'void Planet::DrawPlanet(SDL_Renderer*)' member function declared in class 'Planet'
 void Planet::DrawPlanet(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
                                              ^
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

VSC's task.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Game Sargittarium 2.0",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                //Config parameters
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-mwindows",//This is what is giving me the error

                //Include directories
                "-IG:/SDL2-2.0.8/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/",

                //Sets the files in the program
                "Draw/draw.cpp",
                "Game/game_object.cpp",
                "Game/game.cpp",
                "main.cpp",//Main needs to be the last one

                //Libraries files and directories
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2",
                "-lSDL2_image",
                "-LG:/SDL2-2.0.8/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib",

                "-std=c++11"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

game_object.h:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "../Draw/draw.h"

class Planet
{
    private:
        int pos_x;
        int pos_y;
        int radius;
    public:
        Planet(int x, int y, int r);
        void DrawPlanet(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
};
```

game_object.cpp:

```
#include "game_object.h"

Planet::Planet(int pos_x, int pos_y, int radius)
{
    this->pos_x = pos_x;
    this->pos_y = pos_y;
    this->radius = radius;
}

void Planet::DrawPlanet(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    Draw::CircleFill(renderer, pos_x, pos_y, radius, 255, 255, 255, 255);
}
```

**edit:**
Changing the file name solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that there is another copy of `game_object.h` on your machine that does not declare `DrawPlanet()`, and the compiler is finding that file instead of the one you are expecting? Or maybe `draw.h` is declaring a macro that interfers with `Planet`'s declaration? Why is `draw.h` being included in `game_object.h` at all? `game_object.h` doesn't use anything from `draw.h`, so the `#include` should be moved into `game_object.cpp` instead. Also, why doesn't `game_object.h` have a header guard on it?

Comment: I'm actually quite new to this whole thing of programming so i don't know anything about header guard, but i'll do my research. As for the game_object.h i'll try to change it's name (there are not that much files yet, so that's not a big change) and move the include to the .cpp file. Thanks for the quick answer, i appreciate.